# Ehrhart period collapse for $123\ldots k$-avoiding Birkhoff polytope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, permutations

For $1 \leq r \leq n$, let $\mathcal{B}^n_r$ denote the polytope of all real matrices
$$ \pi = \begin{pmatrix} \pi_{1,1} & \pi_{1,2} & \cdots & \pi_{1,n} \\ 
\pi_{2,1} & \ddots & \cdots & \pi_{2,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\pi_{n,1} & \cdots & \cdots & \pi_{n,n} \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$
for which

- all entries are nonnegative: $\pi_{i,j}\geq 0$;
- the sum along any row or column is equal to one: $\sum_{j}\pi_{i,j}=1$ for all $i$; $\sum_{i}\pi_{i,j}=1$ for all $j$.
- the sum along any upper-left to lower-right chain of entries is at most $r$: $\sum_{k} \pi_{i_k,j_k} \leq r$ for all $(i_1,j_1)<(i_2,j_2) < \cdots < (i_m,j_m)$, where $(i,j) < (i',j')$ means $i\leq i'$, $j\leq j'$ with at least one of these inequalities being strict.

By definition $\mathcal{B}^n_n$ is the *Birkhoff polytope* of doubly-stochastic matrices. In general $\mathcal{B}^n_r$ is a subpolytope of the Birkhoff polytope.

It is well-known that $\mathcal{B}^n_n$ is the convex hull of all permutation matrices, and so in particular $\mathcal{B}^n_n$ is an integral polytope. But this is not true of the $\mathcal{B}^n_r$ in general: for instance,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a vertex of $\mathcal{B}^3_2$. The vertices of $\mathcal{B}^n_r$ which are integral are precisely the permutation matrices of *$123...r+1$-avoiding* permutations.

For a polytope $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ I use $L(\mathcal{P};t)$ to denote the *Ehrhart function* which at nonnegative integers $t$ counts the number of lattice points of $t\mathcal{P}$:
$$ L(\mathcal{P};t) := \# (t\mathcal{P}\cap \mathbb{Z}^n).$$

Since $\mathcal{B}^n_r$ is not an integral polytope, but it is a rational polytope, its Ehrhart function $L(\mathcal{B}^n_r;t)$ is a priori only a *quasipolynomial* in $t$.

**Question**: Is $L(\mathcal{B}^n_r;t)$ in fact always an honest polynomial in $t$?

I have verified this for $1\leq r \leq n \leq 5$ via Sage. The computation that took the longest was $L(\mathcal{B}^5_2;t)$ which is equal to

`(5959/249080832000) * (t + 1) * (t + 2) * (t + 3) * (t + 4) * (t^12 + 30*t^11 + 2534915/5959*t^10 + 22404750/5959*t^9 + 137606217/5959*t^8 + 620455590/5959*t^7 + 2117653385/5959*t^6 + 5561311650/5959*t^5 + 11311600324/5959*t^4 + 17737953240/5959*t^3 + 21126074400/5959*t^2 + 18162144000/5959*t + 10378368000/5959)`

$\mathcal{B}^5_2$ has over 3000 vertices. The other data is available upon request. Probably someone with better computer skills than me can produce more data.

This phenomenon whereby an Ehrhart quasipolynomial has a smaller period than a priori predicted, or in extreme cases is in fact an honest polynomial, is called *Ehrhart period collapse*. It has apparently attracted some attention but remains mysterious.

Even if the above question has a negative answer, I'd still be interested in what could be said about the integer points $t\mathcal{B}^n_r\cap \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$.

P.S., Happy New Year's and here's to a better 2021!

**EDIT**: This question and the answers are now in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02276.

Comment: The fact that all coefficients are positive is also surprising...

Comment: Btw a different perspective is that this polytope is a subpolytope of (a dilate of) the chain polytope of $[n]\times[n]$.

Comment: don't be fooled by small examples; I do not trust positivity of Ehrhart polynomials. For example, the order polytopes have non-negative Ehrhart polynomials for posets with at most 9 vertices, but there are examples with negative coefficients for 20 vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ehrhart function $L(\mathcal B^n_r;t)$ is an honest polynomial. We will show this by following Per's suggestion and proving that it coincides with the Ehrhart function of a certain Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope. The following two steps can probably be combined into one, but I thought it was natural to think of it this way.

**Step 1:** For every $k\in \mathbb N$, the lattice points of $k\mathcal B_r^n$ are in bijection with the set of arrays $\tau\in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0} ^{n\times n}$ that are plane partitions, meaning that $i\geq i', j\geq j'$ implies $\tau_{i,j}\le \tau_{i',j'}$, that also satisfy $kr\geq \tau_{1,1}$ and for each $-n\le s\le n$ we have the traces
$$tr_s(\tau)=\sum_{i}\tau_{i,i+s}=k(n-|s|).$$
*Proof:* This bijection is simply RSK applied to the array $\pi$. The entry $\tau_{1,1}$ records the length of longest increasing subsequence in the biword recording $\pi$, which is exactly the largest possible sum of $\pi_{i,j}$'s along an upper left-lower right chain. This is where the restriction $kr\geq \tau_{1,1}$ comes from.

Let's introduce the partitions $\lambda^n_r=\{r^n0^n\}$ and $\mu^n_r=\{(r-1)^n1^n\}$.

**Step 2:** The plane partitions from the previous lemma are in bijection with the lattice points in the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope $GT(k\lambda^n_r, k\mu^n_r)=kGT(\lambda^n_r, \mu^n_r)$, therefore they are counted by the Kostka number $K(k\lambda^n_r, k\mu^n_r)$.

*Proof:* If we write a Gelfand-Tseltin pattern with top row given by $k\lambda^n_r=\{kr,kr,\dots, kr, 0, 0,\dots, 0\}$ we can erase the leftmost entries that are forced to be $=kr$ and the rightmost entries  that are forced to be $=0$ to be left with a ($45^{\circ}$ rotated) $n\times n$ array. This array is a plane partition with largest part $\le kr$ and the appropriate traces.

For $k\mathcal B^{4}_2$ this bijection looks like simply selecting the array of $*$'s.
$$\begin{matrix}
2k && 2k && 2k && 2k && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0\\
& 2k && 2k && 2k && * && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
&& 2k && 2k && * && * && 0 && 0\\
&&& 2k && * && * && * && 0 \\
&&&& * && * && * && * \\
&&&&& * && * && * \\
&&&&&& * && * \\
&&&&&&& * 
\end{matrix}$$

Combining both steps gives $L(\mathcal B^n_r ;t)=L(GT(\lambda^n_r, \mu^n_r);t)$ which implies the desired polynomiality. It is also expected that positivity of coefficients holds, but I believe it is not known yet.

Comment: This is excellent!

Comment: By the way, in case you're interested in the context in which I started thinking about this polytope, if $P$ is the poset corresponding to the staircase Young diagram $(n-1,n-2,\ldots,1)$, then there is a certain "natural" embedding of $\mathcal{C}(P)$, the chain polytope of $P$, into $\mathcal{B}^{n}_2$; and in particular points in $\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{Z}^{P}\cap\mathcal{C}(P)$ to points in $\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n} \cap \mathcal{B}^{n}_2$ (see Section 6.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.15795).

Comment: There's a product formula for $\#\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{Z}^{P}\cap\mathcal{C}(P)$, i.e., the Ehrhart polynomial of $\mathcal{C}(P)$, due to Proctor (phrased in terms of staricase plane partitions). For $m=1$ the above embedding hits all the rational points, but not for $m>1$, so I wanted to count those to see how many more there are.

Comment: @SamHopkins Fascinating! Can the embedding be used to give a different proof for the order polynomial of $P$?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. For our purposes the point was that these rational points of both polytopes carry a natural cyclic group action (called "picewise-linear rowmotion"), and the embedding is equivariant with respect to that action (essentially, that's how it's defined).

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that the polytope in question is type of a (skew) [Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/gtpatterns.htm#gtKoskta). The corresponding
Ehrhart functions are polynomials, even though the polytopes are non-integral in general.

The classical Birkhoff polytope is an example of this;
you can get it from skew Kostka polynomials associated with the
skew shape, which consists of $n$ disconnected boxes.
Dilation of the polytope with factor $k$ corresponds to having $n$ disjoint rows of length $k$.

Moreover, it is conjectured that the Ehrhart polynomials here always have non-negative coefficients (in fact, a more general conjecture states this for the Berenstein-Zelevinsky polytopes).

Comment: Good point about GT polytopes, Per! Although I don't quite see the realization yet...

Comment: @SamHopkins The connection between Koska coefficients and the Birkhoff polytope is described in section 8, in my  paper here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669815002541?via%3Dihub#s000070 (although I am sure this was known much earlier).